# raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command

Tags: python

When I tried to install Python 3.11.3 using `pyenv 2.3.18` in mac book pro with M1 pro chip, shows error like this:

```
> pyenv install 3.11.3
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.3.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.3/Python-3.11.3.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.3...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.3.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670
Results logged to /var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670/Python-3.11.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 202, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip([*args, *_PACKAGE_NAMES], additional_paths)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670/Python-3.11.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 103, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670/Python-3.11.3/Lib/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/python-build.20230602131834.2670/Python-3.11.3/python.exe', '-W', 'ignore::DeprecationWarning', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/tmp14w0pyb5/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/tmp14w0pyb5/pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/tmp14w0pyb5\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

does anyone facing the same issue? what should I do to fixed it? the macos OS is: `13.3.1 (a)`.  I have tried:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

still could not fixed this issue.